# Word for speaking over others

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary

Is there a word that can be used to describe the act of speaking over another person? Looking particularly to describe the act in the context of a debate where a speaker is unable to respond due to repeated interjections.

Comment: The words that come to mind are to *interrupt*, *hinder*, or *impede* another person.

Comment: What's wrong with 'speaking over'?

Comment: Looking for a stronger expression, something with a more negative context, perhaps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best fit for this case :

> **heckling**

Meaning : Shouting to interrupt a speech with which you disagree.

It has **negative** connotations.

Alternatively :

> **barracking**

References :

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/heckling

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/barracking

Comment: Ooh!  My TOTAL bad Prem!  I deleted my comment and have upvoted the answer - and am further educated by that primarily BE definition of barracking! :-/

Comment: @KristinaLopez , no problem , "all is well that ends well" !!!!

Answer (score 3):

Shouting down? (If at a noisy public meeting) Drowning out? Smothering in interruptions? 
Norwegian has an expression, literally "to talk in someone's mouth". That fits so perfectly that it's a pity English doesn't have it – unless you want to start a fashion.

Comment: Googling didn't help, would love to know this word. Why should Germans have all the compounding fun?!

Comment: @kaben: the Norwegian expression isn't a big compound, but the phrase _å snakke i munnen til noen_, meaning given above. There isn't a verbal noun available.

Comment: Interesting. Then what's the Norwegian equivalent for "putting words in someone's mouth" and it's literal translation?

Comment: Its literal translation would be _å legge ord i munnen til noen_, as you see quite different, but I don't think there is an indigenous phrase for what the British police call "verballing" somebody. I've been speaking bad French rather than Norwegian for seven months, so I might be wrong about that.

Answer (score 1):

> [drown out](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/drown+out)
>
> To make it impossible to hear the sound of something or someone by muffling, masking, or overwhelming it with a louder sound. [[The Free Dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/drown+out)]

Answer (score 0):

> **[barracking](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/barracking)**
>    - *shouting to interrupt a speech with which you disagree*

Answer (score -1):

Surely Mitch (see answers) is right:

***speaking over others***

is quite appropriate:

> [Communication for Business and the Professions: Strategie ...](https://books.google.ca/books?id=xhHiBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA96&dq=%22speaking%20over%20others%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=bkA1Vaf3FoLfsATg84GAAw&ved=0CCgQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=%22speaking%20over%20others%22&f=false)  Page
>   96 Judith Dwyer - 2012 - ‎Preview
>
> This attention can be demanded by speaking loudly, **speaking over
>   others**, using attention-seeking body movements, and ignoring feedback and the views of others.

Comment: It's almost not strong enough an expression. I want to convey a distaste with the practice so I was seeking something with a more negative connotation.

Answer (score -1):

It actually doesn't mean to speak over someone, but this word in terms of the elements that make it up would be perfect if it didn't already have a different meaning:

> **[overtalk](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/overtalk)**
>
> *To talk too much or too long about (something).*

Also:

> **[overspeak](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/overspeak)**
>
> *To speak too much; to use too many words.*

Maybe one of these could be used and evolved over time to mean to talk/speak over someone, like a lot of words change meaning over time. Just requires enough people to start using it that way.